# How to make items responsive?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I'm new to front end work and making sites responsive, so I'm wondering how would I go about making sure that regardless of screen size the space between items is always 20px.

For instance when the screen is not resize it looks fine:
[image]

However, when I resize it down a little the spaces between each item is gone. 
[image]

Then when it is resized further down it goes to 2 items per row which is what I want, but I only want there to be 20px between the items unlike how they appear below:

[image]

I'm using bootstrap 3 and displaying the items within the following:

```
 <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6" id="animateslide">

   <div class="article" id="testarticediv" >

     Items being displayed here....
   </div>
</div>
```

I added the following to my own main.css file:

```
@media(min-width:768px){}
@media(min-width:992px){}
@media(min-width:1200px){}
```

Comment: check my example : 
http://jsfiddle.net/sudhan/6GmM5/10/

it can be achieved with css3 calc property

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be achieved by setting width to div/boxes using css calc property ,
this is the logic to set width of each div, that will make 20px space in all screen sizes :

width: calc( ( full width - total calculated space b/w grid ) / total no:of grid );

```
/* Four Column Layout */
@media(min-width:1200px){
   width: calc( ( 100% - ( 20px * 3 ) ) / 4 ); 
}


/* Three Column Layout */
@media(min-width:800px){
   width: calc( ( 100% - ( 20px * 2 ) ) / 3 ); 
}

/* Two Column Layout */
@media(min-width:650px){
   width: calc( ( 100% - ( 20px * 1 ) ) / 2 ); 
}
```

Comment: How would I go from three columns to two on smaller displays without using bootstrap?

Comment: using "Media Queries".

you can write media queries for standard devices:
http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

using bootstrap or not is your choice,
but things can be achieved by writing custom codes.

do you want me to do examples for two column and three column layouts.

Comment: If you can that would be great!

Comment: I have updated my comment please check,
test your design by resizing your browser window.
adjust "min-width" if needed.   
hope you know how to use media queries.

Comment: Thanks for your update! I took a look at your jsfiddle example and is there an easy way to always center the items without using float left for each different screen size?

Comment: center items with out float,
for items check : http://jsfiddle.net/aslancods/UBYE6/28/

for a item : http://jsfiddle.net/aslancods/A3QCE/

Answer (score 1):

Just add to each box:

```
    margin: 0px 10px;
```

This will set the top and bottom margins to 0 (change this to whatever you desire) and set the left and right margins to 10px. There should then be 20px worth of margins between each item.

Comment: I tried this but it still does not work, that is why I feel like something within bootstrap is overriding this.

Comment: @DomX23 Try adding "!important" to the line. (ie *margin: 0px 10px !important;*)

Comment: No luck using !important either.

Comment: @DomX23 Any chance of getting a live preview? Being able to inspect the element would be very helpful

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried padding each item with 10px at the relevant borders? Two items with a padding of 10px next to each other would equal a 20px.

Comment: What browser are you using? Are you using any CSS debuggers?. They will help you work out what styles are being applied to your elements.

Comment: I tested this out in all browsers with the same results throughout. What kind of CSS debuggers do you recommend I use?

Comment: I use Firefox, and I use this http://chrispederick.com/work/web-developer/. Once installed, press 'alt-shift + y' This will allow you to select elements and show you the styles applied to it. Very useful.